# How to calculate the order of multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{p^x}$ where $p$ is a prime and $x$ is any positive integer ???

Tags: group-theory

Suppose a hensel lifting, $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{p^x}$  where $p$ is a prime and $x$ is any positive integer.

For example $p=5$ and $x=1$, $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{5}=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $|\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{5}|=4$.

Then conduct a lifting $p=5$ and $ x=2$ $p^x=25$

$\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{25}=\{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24\}$

$|\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{25}|=20$

Is there any standard relationship between $|\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{p}|$ and $|\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{p^x}|$???

Comment: Have you heard of the euler totient function?

Comment: I have never heard of this referred to as a Hensel lifting. Where did you encounter that term?

Answer (score 1):

The elements of the multiplicative group modulo $p^x$ are exactly the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^x}$ that are coprime to $p^x$ (in fact $p$). So now you just need to check how many elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^x}$ are not divisible by $p$. It's easy to notice that there are $p^{x-1}$ such elements. Therefore the number of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^x}^{*}$ is $p^x - p^{x-1} = p^{x-1}(p-1)$.

In fact you directly compute the number of integers less than $n$ and comprime to $n$ by the [Euler Totient Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).